# Missing query attribute on result Vue graphql

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql

I can't understand why this error occurs in the console

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag' // import gql

const getBooksQuery = gql`query // describing query
  {
    books{
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  name: "BookList", // template name
  apollo: { // apollo instance
    query: getBooksQuery // query
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please be more specific with what error or output you are getting that is unexpected

Comment: Missing test attribute on result {books: Array(7), Symbol(id): "ROOT_QUERY"}
This error occurs in the console

Comment: What happens when you post that query into graphiql and try the query manually?  Side note: don't need to specify `query` in the graphql-tag

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the apollo property ([docs](https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/api/smart-query.html#options), e.g `bookList`):

```
export default {
  name: "BookList", // template name
  apollo: { 
    bookList: {
       query: getBooksQuery // query
    }
  }
}
```

or even simpler (when you don't need any configs)

```
apollo: {
  bookList: getBooksQuery
}
```