# Vue graphql Missing X attribute on result error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql

New to using vue as a front end but I have vue 2.3.11 as the front end and Django 3 as the backend and using apollo through vue-cli to connect them.

I have a table called `documents` in the backend with just a `name` and an `id` field that I am sending through the front using graphql to display a list of the names. On the console I am getting an error `Missing docList attribute on result`

Vue file template for html

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>All the docs</h2>
    <ul v-for="document in docList" :key="document.id">
        <li>
            <strong>{{ document.name }}</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Vue file script with the graphql query I tested the graphql query on the Django terminal and it works fine.

```
<script>
//Graphql query
import gql from "graphql-tag"

const docList = gql`
query docList {
    documents{
          id,
          name
    }
  }
 `;


export default {
  data() {
    return {
     docList:[],
    };
  },
  apollo: {
    docList:{
      query: docList
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the output in the browser:

[image]

I also looked at several of the same errors and they were [naming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244874/missing-query-attribute-on-result-vue-graphql) or [data mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723183/missing-movies-attribute-on-result-vue-graphql). I tried tweaking the code but don't know what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const docList = gql`
  query docList {    // docList is a query name
    documents{       // 'root' of requested data tree structure
      id,
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Your result starts with `documents` (document nodes array), not with `docsList` (result doesn't contain this name).

```
<ul v-for="document in documents" :key="document.id">
```

Comment: Thanks very excited that this worked. So the solution was changing `docList` in apollo and data sections to `documents`. I have been trying to figure out whats wrong for the last half hour